# Element keeps delaying and sliding

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I am trying to create a portfolio where when an image is hovered on, the caption slides into view. When I hover on the image it takes a significant time to slide into view and when it does it keeps sliding until the mouse leaves the image. Here are snippets of the code used:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("figcaption").hide();
    $("figure").hover(sUp, sDn);
  })

function sUp() {
  $("figcaption").slideUp();
}

function sDn() {
  $("figcaption").slideDown(500);
}
```

```css
.wrkitem {
  padding: 0;
}
.wrkitem a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
figcaption {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  bottom: 0;
}
.imgwrap {
  border: 10px solid rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.71);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imgwrap">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 wrkitem">
    <a href="">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/380/260" alt="">
      </figure>
      <figcaption class="cap-top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</figcaption>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 wrkitem">
    <a href="">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/380/260" alt="">
      </figure>
      <figcaption class="cap-top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</figcaption>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 wrkitem">
    <a href="">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/380/260" alt="">
      </figure>
      <figcaption class="cap-top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</figcaption>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when it shows, you mouseover a child element that then triggers the hover out of the parent, thus causing it to slide back up and repeat. the .hover method isn't really that useful for what you're trying to do, you need mouseenter and mouseleave events instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Althought you can do this with pure CSS, I want to point with your code how can you solve it:

1. Make the `a` tag relative to position it's `figcaption` on the right place.
2. On your JS code use the `a` element to trigger the `hover` event, then *toggle* the `figcaption` relative to that element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("figcaption").hide();
  $(".imgwrap a").hover(function(){
    $('figcaption',this).stop().slideToggle()
  });
})
```

```css
.wrkitem {
  padding: 0;
}
.wrkitem a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}
img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
figcaption {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  bottom: 0;
}
.imgwrap {
  border: 10px solid rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.71);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imgwrap">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 wrkitem">
    <a href="">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/380/260" alt="">
      </figure>
      <figcaption class="cap-top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</figcaption>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 wrkitem">
    <a href="">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/380/260" alt="">
      </figure>
      <figcaption class="cap-top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</figcaption>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 wrkitem">
    <a href="">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/380/260" alt="">
      </figure>
      <figcaption class="cap-top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</figcaption>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @KwabenaBadu glad to help U mate; don't forget to mark it as solved